# How to solve for $x$ in $\sin(\pi x) = x$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, relations

[image]

For the fourth option,

Given $x \in(0,1) $ implying that $[x] = 0$.
And thus on equating $ f(x_0) = g(x_0) $,

I find that $\sin(\pi x_0 ) = x_0$

I have no idea how to solve for x here.
What should I do?

Edit:- On drawing a rough graph, I did find the option to be true, as the graph of $y = \sin(\pi x)$ will intersect the graph of $ y=x $ in the given interval.

So is that enough to prove the option? Or should I find the value at that point as well to verify my answer with reference to the graph?

Comment: But $$\begin{align}\int_0^1g(x)dx&=\int_0^1x\,dx=\left.\frac12x^2\right|_0^1=\frac12\\
&<\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1\sin\pi x\,dx=\left.-\frac1{\pi}\cos\pi x\right|_0^1=\frac2{\pi}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The value of $x$ that makes

$$\sin(\pi x) = x$$

cannot be solved for explicitly in terms of canonized special functions. However, you do not actually need an explicit solution to prove that a solution exists. It is rather easy to do this with the intermediate value theorem. In particular, modify the equation to

$$\sin(\pi x) - x = 0$$

and then you will want to find two points $x_l$ and $x_h$ so that, setting $f_2(x) := \sin(\pi x) - x$ for convenience of writing, provably $f_2(x_l) < 0$ and $f_2(x_h) > 0$. It will then follow, given that $f_2$ is continuous, from the IVT that a solution exists.

Comment: So for $x_l$, I took the point $ \lim{x \to 1^{-}} $ and for $x_h$, I took the point to be equal to 0.5. I did get the answer. But is it correct to take them arbitrarily? Or is there some way to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I might

- Show that $f(x) - g(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.
- Study the intervals on which $f(x) - g(x)$ is increasing and decreasing in $(0,1)$.  (There is one of each.)
- Show that $f(x) - g(x) > 0$ on the increasing interval, so there is no $x_0$ in that interval.  (A short argument uses both that $f(0) = 0$ and the sign of $f'(x) - g'(x)$.)
- Show that $f(x) - g(x)$ changes sign exactly once on the decreasing interval.  The intermediate value theorem gives at least one $x_0$ on that interval.  An argument similar to the previous step shows there are no more, establishing the uniqueness.

Comment: I have found the answer to the question. But i am unable to prove $f(x) - g(x) $ to be continous at $ x = 1$. Can you help me in this?

Comment: @AsadAhmad : You don't need continuity at $x=1$ because $1$ is not in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

f(x)-g(x) is continuous on (1/2,1) and ranges (-1,1/2). Therefore passes through 0.

Beware that A is false. When x increases to approach 1, f(x) decreases to 0 while g(x) increases to 1. Therefore g(x)>f(x).